# Coinbase transaction on ethereum

Tags: mining, blocks, reward

So, I learned that in bitcoin, a coinbase transaction is the first transaction that gets created in the block and it is used to give block rewards to the miner that mined the block. I was curious if this is the same paradigm in ethereum and if it is not, how it differs.

Please correct me if my understanding of coinbase transaction is incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It used to work in the same way on Ethereum, however, a recent update called *[the Merge](https://ethereum.org/en/upgrades/merge/)* changed the paradigm.

There are no more coinbase transactions. Now, the block proposer receives a part of the transaction fee and a part of the reward of the attestations included in the beacon block. If you don't know what beacon blocks and attestations are, learn about the consensus layer of Ethereum.